# Update table with value from another table

Tags: db2

I try to update value from one table with another table by use IP_ID to compare 2 table by following sybtax

```
UPDATE EDWID02.CUSTOMER_MOBILE t1
   SET T1.MOBILE = (
      SELECT T2.MOBILE
      FROM EDWID02.NEW_MOBILE t2
      WHERE T1.IP_ID=T2.IP_ID)
```

The error I found was  DB2 Database Error:

```
ERROR [21000] [IBM][DB2/AIX64] SQL0811N  The result of a scalar fullselect, 
SELECT INTO statement, or VALUES INTO statement is more than one row.  
SQLSTATE=21000
```

even I change  = to in it's told me another error DB2 Database Error:

```
ERROR [42601] [IBM][DB2/AIX64] SQL0104N  An unexpected token "in" was found
following "t1    SET T1.MOBILE".  Expected tokens may include:  "=".
SQLSTATE=42601
```

I am coding in DB2.

Comment: Basically, it's complaining that NEW_MODILE.IP_ID isn't a unique key (there's more than one row with the given value).  You'll need more columns to be able to choose the correct value (update your question if necessary with more info for us).  Changing the statement the way you did will never work, because it's expecting an _assignment_ (`'='`), not a _comparison_ (the `IN` you were attempting to use).

Answer (score 0):

your misunderstanding

```
'UPDATE t1 SET value=onevalue'
```

onevalue needs to be a single value. You may achieve this by (SELECT value FROM t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.id FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY)

Comment: Which would probably work, but may not be the 'correct' answer - what happens if there's more than one value of `T2.MOBILE`?

Comment: the problem seems to be: new_mobile.ip_id is not the unique key, so the update has to "guess" the right value. Maybe an "ORDER BY some date DESC FETCH FIRST 1 ROW oNLY" may be a better result.